# How to open overlay dropdown for outside of responsive table?

Tags: html, responsive

In my case, I have used bootstrap dropdown multi-select inside td where I have also use table responsive class just because of it the dropdown not showing properly. responsive "overflow: hidden" property is hiding that dropdown. Please check below screenshot.

[image: Responsive "overflow: hidden" property is hiding that dropdown]

Comment: Please edit into the question the code you have tried.

Comment: Try to add **position: absolute;** to child element. Please check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kawal/bLv3scyn/5/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked with bootstrap team and they gave me this solution

Add this property in css: transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);

Comment: Yes, it's working I have added this property over the table responsive and set dropdown position to fixed. Thanks, Dhaval